# Validador de HTML do W3C acusa "Empty heading"

Tags: html, validação

Estou tentando validar meu html e ele está me dando a seguinte mensagem:

```
Line 328, Column 34: Empty heading.
<h3 class="titulo-chamada">A internet no controle</h3>
```

Deu a entender que o titulo  está vazio, mas veja que ele tem um  conteúdo.

[Link para o html no codepen](http://codepen.io/rogeralbinoi/pen/cwudF)

Comment: Tem certeza que a origem do erro é esse h3? E ele já está preenchido no próprio HTML, ou seria preenchido mais tarde (por exemplo, com ajax)?

Comment: Então... o validador informou a linha a coluna e esse trecho do codigo que se encontra nesta linha. Não tem ajax, ele está dentro do html mesmo.

Comment: Poderia postar o código todo da página, ou publicá-lo em algum lugar adequado? Pode remover algumas partes, desde que o validador continue apontando o erro.

Comment: Além do código da página, informe também qual validador você está utilizando (seria [o do site da W3C](http://validator.w3.org/)?) e qual a versão-alvo (HTML5, HTML 4.01 strict, HTML 4.01 transitional...)

Comment: estou utilizando o [http://validator.w3.org/check](http://validator.w3.org/check)

Comment: estou usando o HTML5

Comment: Pode verificar esse CodePen? Eu abri aqui e não nenhum HTML.

Comment: [http://codepen.io/rogeralbinoi/pen/cwudF](http://codepen.io/rogeralbinoi/pen/cwudF)

Dê uma olhada

Comment: Postei no pastebin [um exemplo mínimo que reproduz o problema](http://pastebin.com/PtdS5afq). Note que se tirar a tag `<figure>` o problema desaparece, de modo que ela deve estar envolvida de alguma forma.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Semanticamente não é certo colocar um h3 dentro de uma tag figure. Se eu trocar a tag figure e usar uma div, resolve o problema.

Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram!

Comment: Olha que legal, a pessoa que cuida do validador do W3C respondeu! Talvez seja o caso de você marcar a resposta dele como aceita. É um bug do validador.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O significado de "empty" nesse caso não é que a tag não possui conteúdo; é que essa tag não faz referência a uma seção. O significado semântico de um *header* é que ele é "o cabeçalho de uma seção", e não simplesmente uma opção de formatação (como `strong` ou `em`).

Veja [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23739224/520779) para mais detalhes. Ainda estou pesquisando sobre *o que deve ser feito* para consertar isso, quando descobrir posto aqui.

**Atualização:** no seu caso, o uso do cabeçalho dentro de um `article` estaria correto, o problema parece ser por esse `article` estar dentro de um `figure`. Há [vários usos para esse elemento](http://www.maujor.com/blog/2010/04/13/os-elementos-figure-e-figcaption-da-html5/), mas não conheço as consequências de se usá-lo dessa forma. De modo que um meio de solucionar esse problema seria colocar esse `article` em outro lugar (por exemplo numa `div`, como você diz ter feito com sucesso nos comentários).

Comment: Será que precisaria estar dentro de um `<section>`? Nunca vi esse erro antes!

Comment: Eu também pensei nisso, colocar ele dentro de um    'section'...

Comment: @bfavaretto Provavelmente... `<section><h3></h3><p></p></section>` por exemplo. Também nunca tinha visto esse erro antes, teria que fazer uns testes.

Comment: Olá, este h3 esta dentro de um article <article><h3></h3><p>...</p></article>

Comment: Vou colocar no codepen, só um minuto

Comment: Coloquei um link com o code html, ignore os demais erros, pois tirei algumas partes do html

Answer (score 5):

Eu mantenho o validador de HTML5 do W3C. O problema que você reportou é causado por um bug no código do validador. Não é o comportamento esperado. O `<h3>` certamente não está vazio, portanto a mensagem de erro está errada mesmo. Vou tentar consertar esse bug logo. Obrigado por perceber o problema.

---

I'm the maintainer of the W3C HTML5 validator. The problem reported here is caused by a bug in the validator sources. It's not intended behavior. The `<h3>` is definitely not empty. So in this case the error message is just wrong.  I'll try to fix this validator bug soon. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I wasn't expecting this to be read by anyone who doesn't speak Portuguese! You are always welcome here for this kind of feedback, feel free to post in English and we'll translate your answers.

Comment: Hello again. Just to close the loop on this, I wanted to say: I did fix this problem a few months ago in the W3C validator. Sorry for not following up on it here before now, and thanks again for catching it. If you notice other problems please open an issue at https://github.com/validator/validator/issues or send e-mail to www-validator@w3.org or to me directly at mike@w3.org. Cumprimentos

Answer (score 3):

Acho que entendi. Semanticamente não é certo colocar um `h3` dentro de uma tag figure. Se eu trocar a tag figure e usar uma `div`, resolve o problema.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Teste</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <figure class="chamada-banner grid grid-8-12">
                <article class="chamada-box">
                    <span class="categoria">Ponto de vista</span>
                    <span class="description">Entrevista</span>
                    <h3 class="titulo-chamada">A internet no controle</h3>
                    <p>Atualmente, publicam-se on line muito mais informações sobre nós mesmos     do que jamai antes, todos estes dados estão sendo coletados por organizações...</p>
                </article>
            </figure>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Removendo a tag `figure` e usando uma `div` resolve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Teste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chamada-banner grid grid-8-12">
            <article class="chamada-box">
                <span class="categoria">Ponto de vista</span>
                <span class="description">Entrevista</span>
                <h3 class="titulo-chamada">A internet no controle</h3>
                <p>Atualmente, publicam-se on line muito mais informações sobre nós mesmos do que jamai antes, todos estes dados estão sendo coletados por organizações...</p>
            </article>
        </div >
    </body>
</html>
```

Ou então pode-se usar um `span` no lugar do `h3`, caso eu queira usar a tag `figure`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Teste</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <figure class="chamada-banner grid grid-8-12">
                <article class="chamada-box">
                    <span class="categoria">Ponto de vista</span>
                    <span class="description">Entrevista</span>
                    <span class="titulo-chamada">A internet no controle</span>
                    <p>Atualmente, publicam-se on line muito mais informações sobre nós mesmos     do que jamai antes, todos estes dados estão sendo coletados por organizações...</p>
                </article>
            </figure>
        </body>
    </html>
```